# PhantomJS Hangs on Page Errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, casperjs

I am using PhantomJS 2 and the latest CasperJS to test a remote webpage containing some TypeErrors. While logging into the webapp, a popup.created and popup.loaded event are initiated before PhantomJS prints a stacktrace of TypeErrors found when attempting to render the resource. PhantomJS hangs here because PhantomJS does not know how to handle parse errors (Github issue [#10687](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10687)). And my attempts to listen for "error" and "page.error" in both Phantomjs and Casperjs events fail since these TypeError (parse errors) do not throw page.error events (Github issue [#10537](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10537)). I do not own the remote webapp, so I cannot fix these errors. But I need to catch these remote webpage errors and proceed with my testing.

I have unsuccessfully tried to abort loading the resource when the popup.created and popup.loaded events are initiated and I also unsuccessfully attempted to abort the request for the resource when the url of the requested resource matched known url of the .html popup file with TypeErrors.  Does anyone know a better way to handle these TypeErrors?

Comment: This is a known bug in PhantomJS 2.0.0. Have you tried PhantomJS 1.9.8.

Comment: Yes, I had the same behavior when previously using PhantomJS 1.9.8. I upgraded my Phantom version Friday to solve another issue of truncated screenshots (Github issue #10619).